# git svn tool to migrate from SVN containing multiple duplicate repositories

Tags: git, git-svn

I am working on a project where `SVN` repo contains duplicate repositories

```
/trunk/project_v1
/trunk/project_v2
/trunk/project_tomcat_migration_v3
/trunk/empService1
/trunk/empService2
/trunk/empService_random_string_v3

  .
  .
```

`Tags` also contains duplicate repositories.

1. I want to pick the latest version of project svn repository (say project_tomcat_migration_v3) and push it to git repository on master. Rest of the duplicate repositories (say v1 and v2), I want to push on a separate branch. is there any way to achieve this using `git svn` command.
2. If the above thing is not possible with `git svn` is there any way to clone SVN repo and it to the branch of existing git repo 
   something around the line as below:

`git svn clone http://url/trunk//trunk/project_v2 --separate_branch_on_existing_repo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use svn2git. You can use paths specify which repo.

https://github.com/svn-all-fast-export/svn2git

```
create repository project_v1
end repository

create repository project_v2
end repository

match /trunk/project_v1/
repository project_v1
branch master
end match

match /trunk/project_v2/
repository project_v2
branch master
end match
```

Note: tags are branches in SVN and must be declared a little different. `([^/]+)/` is used to match tag name.

```
match /tags/project_v1/([^/]+)/
repository project_v1
branch refs/tags/\1
annotated=true
end match
```

Comment: You are creating separate repos for `trunk/project_v2` and for `trunk/project_v1` this is not the ask. Please read first point from question

Comment: Well figure it out then. This will get you started